# Pertaining to the Form of $\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{F^n},\mathbf{F^m})$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Is the following Proof Correct?

**Theorem.** Given that $T\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{F^n},\mathbf{F^m})$. Show that there exist scalars $A_{j,k}\in\mathbf{F}$ for $j=1,2,...,m$ and $k=1,2,...,n$ such that 
$$T(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}A_{1,k}x_k,\sum_{k=1}^{n}A_{2,k}x_k,...,\sum_{k=1}^{n}A_{m,k}x_k\right)$$
for every $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)\in\mathbf{F^n}$

**Proof.** Let $\Omega=\{\rho_1,\rho_2,...,\rho_n\}$ and $\Psi=\{\eta_1,\eta_2,...,\eta_m\}$ be the set of *standard-basis* for $\mathbf{F^n}$ and $\mathbf{F^m}$ respectively.

Now let $v=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ be an arbitrary vector in $\mathbf{F^n}$ and since the set $\Omega$ constitutes a basis for $\mathbf{F^n}$ it follows that 
$$v=\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k\rho_i\tag{1}$$
it follows that 
$$Tv=T\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_i\rho_k\right)\tag{2}$$
appealing to the *linearity* of $T$ we have 
$$Tv=T\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k\rho_k\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_kT(\rho_k)\tag{3}$$
where $T\rho_k\in\mathbf{F^{m}}$, moreover we know that the set $\Psi$  constitutes a basis for $\mathbf{F^{m}}$ thus
$$Tv=\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_kT(\rho_k)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k\sum_{j=1}^{m}A_{j,k}\eta_j=\sum_{j=1}^{m}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_kA_{j,k}\right)\eta_j\tag{4}$$
now by writing every $\eta_j$ in full we have 
$$Tv=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_kA_{1,k}\right)\eta_1+\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_kA_{2,k}\right)\eta_2+...+\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_kA_{m,k}\right)\eta_m\tag{5}$$
equivalently
$$Tv=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}A_{1,k}x_k,\sum_{k=1}^{n}A_{2,k}x_k,...,\sum_{k=1}^{n}A_{m,k}x_k\right)\tag{6}$$

$\blacksquare$

Comment: Your proof is essentially correct.The only reason I say "essentially" is because there are some typos involving indices, e.g., $v = \sum_{k=1}^n x_k \rho_i$ should read $v = \sum_{k=1}^n x_k \rho_k$.